# How to create Asp.net mvc secure login page authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Hi I have an important task while being completely lost.

My team is building an external website and have already purchased the certificate. I am looking into the asp.net authentication styles and looks like forms authentication is the way to go. However after looking at the microsoft documents [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/forms-authentication) it says that the login information can be seen in cleartext.  Can anyone please point me out in the right direction or let me know where to start this login page?

We have a cybersecurity team that looks at this and will pass or fail our site that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

The cross-site request forgery (CSRF) issues is the primary concern here. If you are using SSL/HTTPS on your site then the password might be sent in clear text, but over an encrypted connection.

Answer (score 0):

The built in default authentication automatically hashes the passwords in the database. It is simple to configure ssl inside IIS . Ontop of your controllers you can  use the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] data annotation to prevent csrf attacks. also put it inside the view as well with htmlhelpers.Im honestly baffled that passwords are sent in clear text. If your super worried about security what I do Is I only authorize certain users to view pages before deployment.

Comment: what about encrypting on the database in case that gets compromised. what is the workflow of that. I can not visualize the steps that all of this happens

Comment: Im really not sure how to encrypt the password on the database but you can always rehash as ive heard Ive never done this neither. the default template with individual authentication in asp,net has an accountController with a register method it gets the password field and puts it in the db from the register view. The Identity system Is very bloated and does a ton of stuff behind the scenes.Id check out this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHMjJ_go8EA&t=8452s